# compareTo issue with sorting an int array

Tags: java, sorting

I have an array of integers that I need to sort in ascending order.  I am required to use `compareTo`.

I have the array sorting with one issue.  The largest number appears first in the array; the rest are sorted in ascending order.

Driver:
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Driver2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int prior,compareResult;
        String task;
        Task[] taskList = new Task[4];
        int [] taskListPrior = new int[4];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for breakfast: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "eatBreakfast";

        Task eatBreakfast = new Task(prior,task);
        System.out.println("Breakfast priority is: " + eatBreakfast.getPriority());
        taskList[0] = eatBreakfast;
        taskListPrior[0] = eatBreakfast.getPriority();

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for lunch: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "eatLunch";

        Task eatLunch = new Task(prior,task);
        System.out.println("Lunch priority is: " + eatLunch.getPriority());
        taskList[1] = eatLunch;
        taskListPrior[1] = eatLunch.getPriority();

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for dinner: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "eatDinner";

        Task eatDinner = new Task(prior,task);
        System.out.println("Dinner priority is: " + eatDinner.getPriority());
        taskList[2] = eatDinner;
        taskListPrior[2] = eatDinner.getPriority();

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for nap: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "haveNap";

        Task haveNap = new Task(prior,task);
        System.out.println("Nap priority is: " + haveNap.getPriority());
        taskList[3] = haveNap;
        taskListPrior[3] = haveNap.getPriority();

        System.out.println("--------------");

        System.out.println("Printing task names and priorities:");
        for(int p = 0 ; p < taskListPrior.length ; p++)
        {
            System.out.println(taskListPrior[p] + " - " + taskList[p]);
        }

        System.out.print("Enter new priority (between 1 & 10) for nap: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        haveNap.setPriority(prior);
        System.out.println("New priority for nap is: " + haveNap.getPriority());
        taskList[3] = haveNap;
        taskListPrior[3] = haveNap.getPriority();
        System.out.println("--------------");

        System.out.println("Printing task names and priorities:");
        for(int p = 0 ; p < taskListPrior.length ; p++)
        {
            System.out.println(taskListPrior[p] + " - " + taskList[p]);
        }

        Task tempTask;
        int tempTaskPrior;
        for(int current = 0 ; current < taskList.length ; current++) 
        {
                for(int i = 1 ; i < (taskList.length) ; i++)
                {
                    compareResult = (taskList[current]).compareTo(taskList[i]);
                    if(compareResult == 1){
                        tempTask = (taskList[i]);
                        tempTaskPrior = (taskListPrior[i]);
                        taskList[i] = (taskList[current]);
                        taskListPrior[i] = (taskListPrior[current]);
                        taskList[current]  = tempTask;
                        taskListPrior[current] = tempTaskPrior;
                    }
                  }
        }

        System.out.println("Printing sorted list of task names and priorities:");
        for(int p = 0 ; p < taskListPrior.length ; p++)
        {
            System.out.println(taskListPrior[p] + " - " + taskList[p]);
        }

        }

}
```

Task class:
    public class Task implements Priority, Comparable{
        public int prior,priorityQuery,priorityNum;
        public String task,taskItem,fullTask;
        Task taskName;

```
    public Task(int priorityQuery, String taskQuery){
        task = taskQuery;
        if (priorityQuery >= minPriority && priorityQuery <= maxPriority)
            prior = priorityQuery;
        else
            System.out.println("Out of valid range, task will have no priority");
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority)
    {
        if (priority >= minPriority && priority <= maxPriority)
            prior = priority;
            else
            System.out.println("Out of valid range, task will have no priority");
    }

    public int getPriority()
    {
        return prior;
    }

    public String toString(){
        taskItem = task;

        return taskItem;
    }

    public Task getTaskName(){
        return taskName;
    }

    public int compareTo(Task compTask){
        if (this.getPriority() < compTask.getPriority())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getPriority() > compTask.getPriority())
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;

    }

}
```

There are actually two parallel arrays, the one used for the `compareTo` method consists only of integers.

Comment: what's the type of `myList` and `myListPriority`? also can you add java tag

Comment: So "comapreTo" is working only on a list of integers.  Your code shows compareTo() method is being used on myList... which suggest an array of Integer objects (not int[ ] ).  Then you have tempTask = myList[i];  So are you saying tempTask is also of type Integer ?  You have a better chance of getting an answer if you post some code that actually runs.

Comment: Also... your if( result == 1 ) logic isn't doing it.  you need to handle result == 0, result < 0 as well as result > 0.  Did you write your own compareTo() method?  Or are you using the one Java provides via the Integer class ?  (Assuming your description is accurate and you're not actually doing something like task1.compareTo( task2 ); you haven't posted enough code for me to tell what is actually going on).

Comment: I have added the full code as requested...

Comment: 2 questions : (1) Why do you use a separated list of priorities, as the Task class already contains the priority ? (2) Why don't you use the static Arrays methods : public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) (with an external comparator) or sort(Object[] a) (with an internal comparator) ?

Comment: @Ivr123 - (1) I was having issues storing the objects in the array and calling the getPrior method.  This was my way around it so I could continue my assignment; (2) I'm not certain this would satisfy the requirements of using compareTo.  I'll have to try and understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with that sort routine.
You start the inner loop from 1 every time so `current` may be > than `i`. 
So it will (in some circumstances) swap items that are in place to out of place.

The proper answer is to use `java.util.Arrays.sort()`.

If you're interested in sorting algorithms write a stand-alone class and implement a unit test script to make sure it works before embedding it your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated initially, compareTo is the requirement. Yes, this is an assignment.  Ultimately, the goal is to identify the top two 'priorities'.

Comment: @abok sort will use compareTo. But if it's an assignment then implement something separately as I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier in my comment, you should try the solution with `Arrays.sort(Object[] array)`:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int prior, compareResult;
        String task;
        Task[] taskList = new Task[4];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for breakfast: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "eatBreakfast";

        Task eatBreakfast = new Task(prior, task);
        System.out.println("Breakfast priority is: " + eatBreakfast.getPriority());
        taskList[0] = eatBreakfast;

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for lunch: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "eatLunch";

        Task eatLunch = new Task(prior, task);
        System.out.println("Lunch priority is: " + eatLunch.getPriority());
        taskList[1] = eatLunch;

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for dinner: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "eatDinner";

        Task eatDinner = new Task(prior, task);
        System.out.println("Dinner priority is: " + eatDinner.getPriority());
        taskList[2] = eatDinner;

        System.out.print("Enter priority (between 1 & 10) for nap: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        task = "haveNap";

        Task haveNap = new Task(prior, task);
        System.out.println("Nap priority is: " + haveNap.getPriority());
        taskList[3] = haveNap;

        System.out.println("--------------");

        System.out.println("Printing task names and priorities:");
        for (Task t : taskList) {
            System.out.println(t.prior + " - " + t.task);
        }

        System.out.print("Enter new priority (between 1 & 10) for nap: ");
        prior = scan.nextInt();
        haveNap.setPriority(prior);
        System.out.println("New priority for nap is: " + haveNap.getPriority());
        taskList[3] = haveNap;
        System.out.println("--------------");

        System.out.println("Printing task names and priorities:");
        for (Task t : taskList) {
            System.out.println(t.prior + " - " + t.task);
        }

        //  Sort this      
        Arrays.sort(taskList);

        System.out.println("Printing sorted list of task names and priorities:");
        for (Task t : taskList) {
            System.out.println(t.prior + " - " + t.task);
        }

    }

}
```

I removed all references to `int [] taskListPrior = new int[4];` which is pointless and replaced your sorting algorithm by a simple `Arrays.sort(taskList)`.

Your class Task may remain unchanged, but you should expand its compareTo method in order to address cases where the priority of both compared tasks are identical. I added a comparison on the task field:

```
public int compareTo(Task compTask) {
    if (compTask==null) return 1;

    if (this.getPriority() < compTask.getPriority())
        return 1;
    else if (this.getPriority() > compTask.getPriority())
        return -1;
    else
        return this.task.compareTo(compTask.task);

}
```

Comment: @Ivr123 - I completely agree that Arrays.sort is the best way to sort the list.  Unfortunately, I have a requirement to implement the Comparable interface and use compareTo to sort the list by priority.

Comment: @abok : I don't get what you say. You know it better. The Task implements Comparable and its compareTo sort the list by priority. Even you wanted an other order for your list, you could create a Comparator class implementing the sort order you really wanted.

Comment: @Ivr123 - Thanks again for your help... for the most part, my sort is working as intended with the exception of the largest number appearing first.  As I am required to use compareTo method implemented by Task in order to do the sort, this is what I have to try and comprehend.